# SharePoint 2013 Page Status Message

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Is there a way to add status to a page(suppose home page) of a SharePoint site using PowerShell? I found ways to do it using javascript (SP.UI.Status) and server side code using c# (SPPageStatusSetter). But my preference in PowerShell. So is there any way to do it with PowerShell?

Comment: using powershell you can add a content editor webpart to the page and add the status text inside that.

Comment: Thanx for response. But i am aware of that option. I have tried that but its not as simple as status option since we have to determine the zone id and zone.